# How to view luigi error log if task get killed

Tags: python, luigi

I'm trying to run Luigi task which will read few million records from a table and write to a csv. Unfortunately, the job got killed, but I couldn't find any traceback error or any clue to fix this.

> INFO: Informed scheduler that task   ExportData__99914b932b   has
>   status   PENDING INFO: Done scheduling tasks INFO: Running Worker with
>   1 processes DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work... DEBUG: Pending tasks:
>   1 INFO: [pid 26002] Worker Worker(salt=557665440, workers=1,
>   host=unknown, username=root, pid=26002) running   ExportData() Killed

Comment: problem fixed after fine tune the query to specific column. process likely got killed due to insufficient memory to hold the large dataset.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it was related to insufficient memory as well. I'm running a small machine, so I had to increase the SWAP size.